# R: Unable to use package reticulate with SYSTEM account under Windows

Tags: python, r, windows, reticulate

I am trying to call a `Python` script without using R Markdown in Reticulate in a R script. I have a requirement to call the R script by a third-party application (using SYSTEM account) which will then call the Python script. Basically I want to use R variables inside Python. While it works fine when I execute it logged in Windows it does not when executing by the SYSTEM account in Windows. I have `Python` installed under C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe

R code:

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\python.exe")
library(reticulate)
use_python("C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\python.exe", required = T)
message <- paste("Text from R", format(Sys.Date(), "%c"), sep = " ")
py_run_file("test_script.py")
```

Python code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="test_script.log", level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s %(message)s',datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S')
logging.debug(r.message)
```

Output when logged on:

```
DEBUG: 10/30/2020 08:02:10 Text from R sex out 30 00:00:00 2020
```

Output when running with SYSTEM account:

```
DEBUG: 10/28/2020 02:28:37 <function make_python_function.<locals>.python_function at 0x00000243D21E3168>
```

> Windows 10
> R version 4.0.3
> Python version 3.8.6
> Reticulate version 1.18

What is this `make_python_function` and how to make it work under SYSTEM account? Thanks for any info!

Comment: You may need to set up an Rprofile for that account or on a site-wide basis. You may need to load more packages and/or set environment variables for libraries for the batch process' workspace. See `?Startup` and `?BATCH`